# Winform iamge flashes briefly and disappears

Tags: winforms, .net-3.5

New to winform, so excuse the elementary question:

I added a picture box on the form, initially hidden. In response to a button click, if certain condition is true, I make the picture visible.

The problem is when I click the button and the condition is true, it shows the broken image ("Error Image"). On the design page, the image is displayed fine.

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text))
    {
        //Controls.Add(image1);
        image1.Show(); 

        //image1.Visible = true;
    }
```

The image is part of the project; its build action is set to "Embedded Resource" and "Copy to output directory" is set to "do not copy". Also, when I check the project resource page, I see the image and its "Persistence" property is set to "Embedded in .resex".

Not sure what else I can do aside from copying the image to output directory.

Comment: I had to copy the image, manually, to the output folder. Is this how it works for Winforms? I also tried pressing F4 in properties, when image was selected, and chose "Project Resource File" as resource context but it didn't help. Copying the image to output works!

Comment: If your problem is how to address the image, then that is the code you should be showing.  How do you assign this resource image to the picture box?

Comment: I set the image location. Also, I used the properties of the picture box and set its Resource Context to be Project Resource File and selected the image. Did I miss something? On the project property page, under Resources, if I select "Images" I can see the image and it is supposed to be "Embedded Resource"

Answer (score 0):

I was modifying the properties, in VS properties panel, under "Asynchronous" and setting up picture box's image location. I did not set up image location under "Image"!! Dumb newb question!